# Formula to adjust two numbers from ratio to another

Tags: percentages, ratio

I have databases of people in countries, with sex, but the sex ratio of the databases don't always correspond with the actual sex ratio of the country.

I am looking for a formula to be able to multiply the sex that is under represented in the database, so it corresponds to the actual sex ratio of the country.

*Sex ratios are presented as male:female*.

Two examples where females are over represented:

```
**Qatar**
Sex ratio in database: 2.35
Actual sex ratio: 3.41
Males: 194,352
Females: 76,563
Total: 270,915

**Botswana**
Sex ratio in database: 0.89
Actual sex ratio: 1.04
Males: 176,790
Females: 203,742
Total: 380,532
```

An example where males are over represented:

```
**Sudan**
Sex ratio in database: 2.4
Actual sex ratio: 1.02
Male: 129,565
Female: 51,207
Total: 180,772
```

In the case of Qatar I want to be able to increase the males from 194,352 (which is a sex ratio of 2.35 males to females) to be in line with the actual sex ratio of the country (3.41).

This can be achieved with the sum:

194,352 × ***1.345*** = 261,403

This gives a ratio of 3.41 males to females with 261,403 : 76,563.

However, I can't find a way to arrive at the 1.345 number. Can anyone assist?

Comment: In Qatar, why is it the case that females are over represented?

Comment: @Clayton, there are 3.41 men per women in Qatar, due to economic migration. My database only has a ratio of 2.35.

Comment: Ah. In all other cases, the over represented sex corresponds to the raw numbers (which is what I was paying attention to, not the ratios presented). Thanks

Comment: Whose voting me down? Ya' git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $2.35$ is not correct.  $\frac{194352}{76563} \approx 2.538$.  Then $\frac {3.41}{2.538} \approx 1.344$.  You just need to divide the desired ratio by the existing ratio.  Your other printed sex ratios also do not match the result of dividing males by females.

Comment: Thanks, I had two issues prior to this calculation, which explains why I was getting nowhere.